# Really really basic Obj-C question about passing instance variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, scoping

Hi sorry about such a dumb question
I am changing a variable value depending on the index of a segmented control but then want to use this variable in a calculation that follows; am sure this has something to do with variable scoping?

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(UIButton *)button {
if( [sSeg selectedSegmentIndex]==1){
    float  s=0.5;
    NSLog(@"s=%f", s);
}
else if ([sSeg selectedSegmentIndex]==0)
{
    float s=1; 
    NSLog(@"s=%f", s);
}
NSLog(@”s now = %f”, s);
```

}

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Just declare your float var in your interface file between the curly brackets like float s; and in your IBAction method (and anywhere else) you can access it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(UIButton *)button {
    float s = 0;
    if( [sSeg selectedSegmentIndex]==1){
        s=0.5;
        NSLog(@"s=%f", s);
    }
    else if ([sSeg selectedSegmentIndex]==0)
    {
        s=1; 
        NSLog(@"s=%f", s);
    }
    NSLog(@”s now = %f”, s);
```

}

Yeah, its the scope - a variable is only visible inside your curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(UIButton *)button {
    float s;
    if( [sSeg selectedSegmentIndex]==1){
        s=0.5;
        NSLog(@"s=%f", s);
    }
    else if ([sSeg selectedSegmentIndex]==0)
    {
        s=1; 
        NSLog(@"s=%f", s);
    }
    NSLog(@”s now = %f”, s);
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I tried declaring float s outside of the if statement (as in answer above) but it still not accessible below the if statement. And Im getting local declaration of s hides instance variable warnings.

Comment: And if I declare float s=1 outsid ethe function (but within action) I get from log s=1, s=0.5 s=1

Comment: Hmm I've tried declaring the float everywhere! This should work?! time for a cup of tea :( ...

Comment: Are you sure you removed the `float` declaration inside the if and else clauses?

Comment: That's exactly what I did wrong. Doh!!  Thanks+++ for all the help